# Cutting down calculations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Okay so I was solving some questions on vectors but then I came across a question which I could not  solve quickly enough . The method I used is basically super lengthy and prone to errors . I had to find the values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ using the two relations (comparing them).

Basically I found the coordinates of the same point once in terms of $\lambda$ and then in terms of $\mu$ .

$$\left (\frac{16\lambda + 6}{\lambda +1}\right),\left (\frac{-19\lambda - 7}{\lambda +1}\right),\left (\frac{-4\lambda}{\lambda +1}\right) \cdots (1)$$

$$\left (\frac{2\mu}{\mu +1}\right),\left (\frac{-5\mu+3}{\mu +1}\right),\left (\frac{10\mu-6}{\mu +1}\right) \cdots  (2)$$

On comparing I eventually get $\lambda=\frac{-1}{3}$ and $\mu=1$.

The thing is this takes too much time ? Is there a better way to do this ?

P.S. - I made $3$ equations and solved them and basically made more equations and solved them to get these values.

Comment: It would be very nice if you could show us the original problem and how you reduced it to those equations - it could be that there was an easier alternative way that completely bypasses writing those equations in the first place, rather than an alternative way of solving them.

Comment: the question basically asks to find the intersection points of the two given lines in space. I got these two equations as a result of *section formula*.

Comment: And ... how were the lines given? Parametrically or via a system of equations? Or just as going through a given pair of points?

Comment: Basically 4 points were given , I generated the required lines and  then assumed that they intersect at a point which divides one line in ratio $\lambda:1$ and other in $\mu:1$

Comment: I think the use of section formula may be why you got more complicated expressions than necessary. If the given points are $A$ and $B$, and $X$ is on the line $AB$, then you can write $\vec{AX}=\alpha\vec{AB}$, i.e. $X=A+\alpha(B-A)$, where $\alpha$ is unknown - that would make everything at least linear (no unknowns in the denominators!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in the comments that the problem has originated as a question to find the intersection of two lines $AB$ and $CD$, where the co-ordinates of the points $A,B,C,D$ are given.

**Solution**: Express $X$ via those points as follows:

$$\vec{AX}=\alpha\vec{AB}\text{, i.e. }X=A+\alpha(B-A)$$
$$\vec{CX}=\beta\vec{CD}\text{, i.e. }X=C+\beta(D-C)$$

This gives us the vector equation:

$$\alpha(B-A)-\beta(D-C)=C-A$$

which, when written in co-ordinates, gives you a system of *linear* equations with unknowns $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Solving this system provides you with $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and therefore with $X$. Beware: this system may have zero, one or multiple solutions in ($\alpha, \beta$).

**Example**: With $A(6,-7,0)$, $B(16,-19,-4)$,$C(0,3,-6)$,$D(2,-5,10)$, the calculation goes as follows:

$$X=(6,-7,0)+\alpha((16,-19,-4)-(6,-7,0))=(6+10\alpha, -7-12\alpha, -4\alpha)$$
$$X=(0,3,-6)+\beta((2,-5,10)-(0,3,-6))=(2\beta, 3-8\beta, -6+16\beta)$$

which gives us the system:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}6+10\alpha&=&2\beta\\-7-12\alpha&=&3-8\beta\\-4\alpha&=&-6+16\beta\end{array}$$

or:

$$\begin{array}{lll} 10\alpha&-2\beta&=-6\\-12\alpha&+8\beta&=10\\-4\alpha&-16\beta&=-6\end{array}$$

Solving this gives a unique solution $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2}, \beta=\frac{1}{2}$, which then in turn gives $X=(1, -1, 2)$.

Comment: $A(6,-7,0) , B(16,-19,-4) , C(0,3,-6) , D(2,-5,10)$ .Find the point of intersection of $AB$ and $CD$.There you go . Please post your working here because I didn't really understand what you were trying to tell me.

Comment: @Tanuj Updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why does this work? What exactly did you do geometrically? Can you kindly explain? Possibly with a figure? Is this any concept of vectors? Please let me know how you wrote $X$ in terms of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Tanuj It is just the vector equation of the line, through two points; see e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r24zBidwago

Comment: Thanks man! Great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are the values in (1), and $b_1, b_2, b_3$ those in (2), we see immediately $b_3=-2\,b_2$, and $a_3=-2\,a_2$ means $38\lambda+14=-4\,\lambda$, i.e. $\lambda=-1/3$. $a_1=b_1$ now gives $\mu=1$.

Comment: smart observation ! Not sure though if that would work in other problems :/ +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could be a shortcut. We solve for the two equations $$\frac{16\lambda+6}{\lambda+1}=\frac{2\mu}{\mu+1}\implies 7\mu\lambda+8\lambda+2\mu+3=0\\\frac{-4\lambda}{\lambda+1}=\frac{10\mu-6}{\mu+1}\implies7\mu\lambda-\lambda+5\mu-3=0$$ Subtracting gives $$9\lambda-3\mu+6=0\implies\mu=3\lambda+2$$ Plugging this into the first equation, $$7(3\lambda+2)\lambda+8\lambda+2(3\lambda+2)+3=21\lambda^2+28\lambda+7=0\implies 3\lambda^2+4\lambda+1=0$$ giving $\lambda=-\dfrac13,-1$, but $\lambda\neq-1$ due to the denominator so we have $\boxed{\lambda=-\frac13\implies\mu=-1}$